# Add Scale to PhotoEditorSDK

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoeditorsdk

In the Desktop HTML version I don't find the way to edit the image height and width dimensions.

I'm trying to figure out if there is any built-in UI Button to resize and scale the image without cropping it. I need this even if it changes the image scale factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are right. Currently, it is not possible to scale or resize an image via one of our UIs. You may do it programmatically though.

However, we are definitely considering extending the UIs.

Best regards

Daniel